# How to reset the index after inserting one dataframe into another

Tags: python, pandas

I want to insert values from one data frame to another data frame, when a particular condition is met. I want to insert it to the top of the dataframe. PL is the source dataframe and sub is the destination Data frame. This is the following code I used,

```
pl=pd.DataFrame.from_records(max) 

sub=pd.concat([pl[pl.id==3],sub])
```

Once I do this, one value from pl is insert to the top of the sub data frame. but I am having a problem here. The index value of pl are into sub and the index values are as follows,

```
[ 757    0    1 ..., 3673]
```

I want to change the index like `[0,1,...,3674]`. Can anybody tell me how to do that in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reset your index to start from zero, you can call `reset_index`:

```
sub=sub.reset_index()
```